# Facebook Graph API with PHP connection

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i want to display facebook friends on my website and i want to use facebook graph api for that,

### please

Thanks
Prakash
[Facebook Graph API with PHP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683793/facebook-graph-api-with-php-connection)

Comment: Since this is your first question here - http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: No one will do your homework. Start by reading the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) obviously!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial might help: [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)
It includes example as well.

Comment: sudhir,
github exampls are vary useful.
i got my answer, thank u vary much.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an access token for yourself by going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and then you may be able to retrieve your friends by accessing https://graph.facebook.com/_YOUR_USER_ID_/friends?access_token=xx and then the profile images can be retrieved using the following graph API call - https://graph.facebook.com/_FRIEND_PROFILE_ID_/picture?type=square

Of course, for more details, the Facebook Documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) is where you go to.